# thymeleaf Spring how to send complex object to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a project `Spring Boot` with `Thymeleaf` as front-end, I need to create an object from a form in view, this Object is complex:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks", catalog = "explorerrh")
public class Tasks implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer idtasks;
private Employee employee;
private String taskName;
private String taskDescrption;
private Date taskTime;
private String statut;
```

As you see the bean `Tasks` has an attribute name `Employee`.
Now I want to create a form to create a `"Task"` 
So in controller I pass the bean `Tasks` as an empty bean and bean `Employee` like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView  loginUser(@ModelAttribute Login login, Model model) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.
            getEmployeeByMail(login.getMailAddress());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
        mav.addObject("employee", employee);
        mav.addObject("date", mediumDateFormat.format(date));
        mav.addObject("task", new Tasks());
        return mav;

}
```

Then:
In view `Thymeleaf` :

```
<form role="form" action="/addTask" th:action="@{/addTask}"  th:object="${task}" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskTitle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Task Title</label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" th:field="*{taskName}" id = "taskTitle" placeholder = "Enter Task title"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskTitle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>employee</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           th:field="*{employee}" th:value="${employee}" id="employeeTask"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskDescription">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Task Description</label>
                    <textarea name="taskDescription" th:field="*{taskDescrption}" class="form-control" rows="5" id="taskDescription"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                        <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                               name="taskDateTime" th:field="*{taskTime}" type="text"/>
                        <span class="add-on">
                          <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
                          </i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="taskStatut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Task statut</label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" th:field="*{taskStatut}" id = "taskStatut" placeholder = "Enter Task statut"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> add task</button>
            </form>
```

Finally I implement a controller to intercept this form:

```
   public ModelAndView addTask(@ModelAttribute Tasks tasks) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
    Employee employee = employeeService.
            getEmployeeByIdemployee(String.valueOf(
                    tasks.getEmployee().getIdemployee()));
    tasks.setStatut("Open");
    tasks.setEmployee(employee);
    tasksService.addTask(tasks);
    return mav;
}
```

I have this error when sending the form:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 13 23:47:19 GMT+01:00 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='tasks'. Error count: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The error said you that object can't be saved due to validation errors. Also it said that you have 2 validation errors.
In your form `th:object` named `task`, so rename it in submit method. Also you need to add `BindingResult` after bean to handle errors :

```
public ModelAndView addTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Tasks tasks, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //errors handling
    }
}
```